# MySql Function inside stored procedure

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures

Is that possible to write a function inside MySql stored procedure?

I have set of queries like this.

```
INSERT INTO party (Description, ShortName)
SELECT CompanyName, NULL FROM tempParentSource;
SET @PartyID =  LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO partyrole (PartyID,RoleTypeID)
SELECT @PartyID , 5;
SET @ParentSourcePartyRoleID =  LAST_INSERT_ID();

-- insert parentSource table 
INSERT INTO parentsource (OrgPartyRoleID, CompanyName, ContactNumber, ContactName, ContactEmail, Ext, ContactTelephone)
SELECT @ParentSourcePartyRoleID , CompanyName, ContactPhone,  ContactName, ContactEmail, Ext, ContactTelephone FROM tempParentSource;
SET @ParentSourceID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

There are few conditions to check and execute given set of queries. Following are the conditions

```
  IF (@ParentSourceID IS NOT NULL  AND @ParentSourcePartyRoleID != @CurOrgPartyID)
  ELSEIF (@ParentSourceID IS NULL AND  @ParentSourcePartyRoleID IS NOT NULL)
  ELSEIF (@ParentSourcePartyRoleID IS NULL AND @CompanyName IS NOT NULL)
```

Inside of these conditions, i need to execute above given set of queries. Instead of repeating those queries inside each and every condition. If that is possible, how can i write a function and call inside those conditions?

Comment: 'Is that possible to write a function inside MySql stored procedure' - no. but it is possible to execute one.

Comment: *can i write a function and call inside those conditions?* Separately (as independent function) - yes. In procedure code - no.

Comment: P.Salman, yes, it is already executing and work fine.But i'm repeating the same queries again and again. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but I am not really sure what your current code (with repetitions) looks like, that you want to simplify. Can you post this?